# Python UnicodeEncodeError when Outputting Parsed Data from a Webpage

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, encoding

I have a program that parses webpages and then writes the data out somewhere else. When I am writing the data, I get

> "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position
>   19-21: ordinal not in range(128)"

I am gathering the data using lxml.

```
name = apiTree.xpath("//boardgames/boardgame/name[@primary='true']")[0].text
worksheet.goog["Name"].append(name)
```

Upon reading, http://effbot.org/pyfaq/what-does-unicodeerror-ascii-decoding-encoding-error-ordinal-not-in-range-128-mean.htm, it suggests I record all of my variables in unicode. This means I need to know what encoding the site is using.

My final line that actually writes the data out somewhere is:

```
wks.update_cell(row + 1, worksheet.goog[value + "_col"], (str(worksheet.goog[value][row])).encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
```

How would I incorporate using unicode assuming the encoding is UTF-8 on the way in and I want it to be ASCII on the way out?

Answer (score 1):

You error is because of:

```
str(worksheet.goog[value][row])
```

Calling `str` you are trying to encode the ascii, what you should be doing is encoding to utf-8:

```
 worksheet.goog[value][row].encode("utf-8")
```

As far as *How would I incorporate using unicode assuming the encoding is UTF-8 on the way in and I want it to be ASCII on the way out?* goes, you can't  there is no ascii latin `ă` etc... unless you want to get the the closest ascii equivalent using something like [Unidecode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode).

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have figured my own problem out.

```
apiTree.xpath("//boardgames/boardgame/name[@primary='true']")[0].text
```

Actually defaults to unicode. So what I did was change this line to:

```
name = (apiTree.xpath("//boardgames/boardgame/name[@primary='true']")[0].text).encode('ascii', errors='ignore')
```

And I just output without changing anything:

```
wks.update_cell(row + 1, worksheet.goog[value + "_col"], worksheet.goog[value][row])
```

Due to the nature of the data, ASCII only is mostly fine. Although, I may be able to use UTF-8 and catch some extra characters...but this is not relevant to the question.

:)

Comment: Why are you trying to encode to ascii in the first place?

Comment: It's just the name of a game in English. I don't need anything more than Ascii...but I suppose I could use UTF-8.